# Getting the dimensions of a zoomed image

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

I have a box div with this css property: `width:400px; height:300px; overflow:hidden;`. Inside I have an image. 
With Iscroll4 I zoom and move the image inside the box.
Works all fine but with Jquery if I Get the dimension of the zoomed image the function will  return always 400px of with dimension and 300px of height dimension.

```
$('#dimpos').bind("click", function (event, ui) {
  var imgzoomed = $('#Container img');
  var position = imgzoomed.position(); /* <----------- Work Fine   */
  var dim_width = imgzoomed.css("width"); /* <----------- Don't Work but return 400px */
  var dim_height = imgzoomed.height(); /* <-----------  Don't Work but return 300px    */
  $('#gdp').text("Position (left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top + ") - Width: " + dim_width + "  Height: " + dim_height);
});
```

---

This is the problem:

When I zoom the image the new width and the height is for example width 500px and height 600px but the visible part of the image is the dimension of the div box (width 400px and height 300px) so if I use the Jquery width() or css("width") it will return always 400px.

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle Demo. Is there only one `#Container` and only one `img` inside?

Answer (score 0):

did u tried parseInt method? this way should return only number;

```
var dim_width = parseInt($('#Container img').css("width"));
var dim_height = parseInt(imgzoomed.height());
```

is there an example to show us about with this question?